# How to make ImageView width match the scaled image content width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I was wondering, how can I make my ImageView width, match the scaled image content width.

I'm using `wrap_content` for `ImageView`.

This works very well, if the image content is small sized.

However, it doesn't work well, for a large portrait or large landscape image.

Here's my outcome.

[image]

1st row is what I wish to achieve. It is using a small image.

- Respect image content width by using `wrap_content`.
- Respect left `TextView`s' height, by using `match_parent`.

However, when comes to 2nd row and 3rd row, it is not something what I expect.

2nd row is using large portrait image. 3rd row is using large landscape image.

- Doesn't respect image content width.
- Image content is not right most.

For `ImageView`, I'm using the following XML

```
<ImageView
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/landscape" />
```

---

Here's my complete layout XML

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/about_card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="false" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="?attr/secondaryTextColor"
                    android:text="CEO"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space_among_cards"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="?attr/primaryTextColor"
                    android:text="Mark_Zuckerberg"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:background="#ff0000"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_refresh_black_18dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="?attr/secondaryTextColor"
                    android:text="CEO"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space_among_cards"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="?attr/primaryTextColor"
                    android:text="Mark_Zuckerberg"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:background="#ff0000"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/portrait" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="?attr/secondaryTextColor"
                    android:text="CEO"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space_among_cards"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="?attr/primaryTextColor"
                    android:text="Mark_Zuckerberg"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:background="#ff0000"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/landscape" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Here's the image I'm using

1. [Small image](https://github.com/martykan/forecastie/raw/master/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_refresh_black_18dp.png)
2. [Large portrait image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/31/Mark_Zuckerberg_at_the_37th_G8_Summit_in_Deauville_018_v1.jpg/1200px-Mark_Zuckerberg_at_the_37th_G8_Summit_in_Deauville_018_v1.jpg)
3. [Large landscape image](https://timedotcom.files.wordpress.com/2017/08/170808-mark-zuckerberg-more-money-than-jeff-bezos.jpg)

Any idea how I can make `ImageView` behaves the following when using large image?

1. Respect the scaled image content width
2. Make image content right most

---

### Update

I had tried to use `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`. However, it get thing worst as you can see the large portrait image is pushing its left `TextView`s away.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap();` ?? You can obtain the height of the View directly and when you set the image use the scaled bitmap and the width will change accordingly. also use ImageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP)

Answer (score 1):

[image: Result is]

Try this:

```
<ImageView
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="#ff0000"
      android:scaleType="fitEnd"
      android:src="@drawable/portrait" />
```

Comment: But, can u make the change on small `ic_refresh_black_18dp` as well? It will scale up unnecessary - https://i.imgur.com/KJHQCtH.png

Comment: Yes it scales. `fit` scales image.

Comment: It is not the effect I wish to achieve. As you can see in https://i.imgur.com/KJHQCtH.png  , after small image scale up, the image becomes blur.

Comment: Then check for `height` and `width` of `ImageView` dynamically . If only height/width more than `parent layout` apply `scaleType ="fitEnd"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
adjustViewBounds="true"
```

On the ImageView, (see [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:adjustViewBounds)), to make sure the view only uses the necessary width.

Answer (score 0):

> i have added weightSum to root layout and give weight to the child
>   layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                    android:id="@+id/about_card_view"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:weightSum="100">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="40"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#02B8B9"
                    android:text="CEO"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#02B8B9"
                    android:text="Mark_Zuckerberg"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:background="#ff0000"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="60"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/mic_pic" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:weightSum="100">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="40"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#02B8B9"
                    android:text="CEO"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#02B8B9"
                    android:text="Mark_Zuckerberg"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:background="#ff0000"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="60"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/images1" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="100">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="40"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#02B8B9"
                    android:text="CEO"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#02B8B9"
                    android:text="Mark_Zuckerberg"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:background="#ff0000"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="60"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/test_image" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```